# Recycler view is forgetting child position

Tags: android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a recyclerview hosting a multiple viewholder adapter one Of The viewholders has a custom wrapcontent viewpager for sliding imageview. First the viewpager is requesting focus I mean while scrolling the recyclerview it jumps to the viewpager, secondly the recycler view is forgetting it child position please how do I go about it.

Comment: Have you tried with viewholder.adapterposition ?

Comment: No. Could you please explain more